# Wordpress site didn't allow me to send values with the form

Tags: wordpress, sendmail, contact-form-7

WordPress forms didn't send emails, I have tried more than one plugins but all didn't send
1-SMTP email test work fine
2- there is no reCAPTCHA verification
3- I tried to delete all caches
now, forms can't get the value from the form and give (One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.) in orange color even fields are filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be on your hosting side try to speak your hosting company.

Comment: I did and they told me, there is no issue from the server side